# Subtract day in specific format

Tags: perl, date

I would like to subtract one day each time through the loop in format %Y%m%d, but when I run this code, it shows some weird numbers.

```
my $date = Time::Piece->strptime("20170306", "%Y%m%d");
$date = $date->strftime("%Y%m%d");

my $i = 7;
while($i > 0) {
    $date -= ONE_DAY;
    print "Date: " . $date . "\n";
    $i--;
}
```

Output:

```
Date: 20083906
Date: 19997506
Date: 19911106
Date: 19824706
Date: 19738306
Date: 19651906
Date: 19565506
```

Comment: Your problem is the output, right?

Comment: And the input too!

Comment: `$date = $date->strftime("%Y%m%d");` - this is a bad idea, because you replace a `Time::Piece` object that you can manipulate, with a string (numeric) that you can't as easily - leave `strftime` until you're outputting it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `strftime` for each iteration. Do not assign the return value of that call `$date` or it will overwrite your object with a string. This line is wrong:

```
$date = $date->strftime("%Y%m%d");
```

I've removed the parsing from your code for this example as I don't know what your input is.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Time::Piece;
use Time::Seconds;

my $date = localtime;

my $i = 7;
while($i > 0) {
    $date -= ONE_DAY;
    printf "Date: %s\n", $date->strftime('%Y%m%d');
    $i--;
}
```

This prints a list of days, going from today backwards.

```
Date: 20170312
Date: 20170311
Date: 20170310
Date: 20170309
Date: 20170308
Date: 20170307
Date: 20170306
```

Comment: If I use strftime I got Can't locate object method "strftime" via package "20256706".. I just used: print "Date: " . $date->strftime("%Y%m%d") . "\n";

Comment: That's because you overwrite your object with the formatted string. I removed that part. I'll make it clearer in a bit.

Comment: I added my parsing

Comment: yea, but i get same error when I use print "Date: " . $date->strftime("%Y%m%d") . "\n"; too

Comment: @tomsk that's because your variable is not a Time::Piece object any more. You are assigning to it above the loop.